# Set sms as read in Android

Tags: android, sms

In my application I need to read sms coming from only a number, and when i receive it I need to set it as read automatically, without setting it in the sms android application, but from my app. How can I do?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A short example:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
  // Retrieve sms
  // see column "address" for comparing

  // Then update the sms and set the column "read" to 1
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have a problem: `while (cursor.moveToNext() && !stato) {
    String asd = new String(cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex("read")));
    Toast.makeText(context, asd, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }` If i set address in getColumnIndex there is no problem, but if i set read or other column name it doesn't work. Why? Thanks!

Comment: Last time I wrote something for android it's about a year ago. Sorry, but I don't know the answer. But there are several Uri's for the sms API. You can try to write the sms to a different one as **content://sms/inbox** and remove the old in the inbox.

Comment: Can you post your solution? This would probably help other users with the same problem.

Comment: String asd = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("read")); i forget to post it, sorry

Comment: but after updating the read state from content provider default sms application still show this sms is unread

Answer (score 14):

Let me update this:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("read",true);
getContentResolver().update(Uri.parse("content://sms/"),values, "_id="+SmsMessageId, null);
```

SmsMessageId is `_id` of message, which you find in SMS database.

Comment: This is supported till what API level?