# mark SMS as read android

Tags: android, sms, android-contentresolver

Hello I am trying to mark all SMS as read on android 
I tried all pisible solution but I couldn't  seems like I have something wrong 
I tried the follwing solutions

- [Android: how to mark sms as read in onReceive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8637271/android-how-to-mark-sms-as-read-in-onreceive)
  [Set sms as read in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6059604/set-sms-as-read-in-android)
  http://looksok.wordpress.com/2013/09/07/android-tutorial-mark-sms-as-read-unread/

here is my code

```
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_smslist);
            markSmsAsRead();
            setSMSRead();
    }

 public void markSmsAsRead() {

        Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
        String selection = "read = ?";
        String[] selectionArgs = {"0"};

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("read", true);
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        context.getContentResolver().update(uri, values, selection, selectionArgs);
    }
    public void setSMSRead()
    {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("read", true);
       // String where = "read = 0";
       // String where = "_id < 100000";
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        context.getContentResolver().update(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), values, "_id<" + "100000", null);

    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to mark all text messages as read on Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33678063/how-to-mark-all-text-messages-as-read-on-android)

Answer (score 2):

In order to mark sms's as read your app must be default SMS application

Comment: +1 This is correct. See http://android-developers.blogspot.ru/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html