# How to mark all text messages as read on Android?

Tags: java, android, sms, inbox

I'm trying to mark all text messages as read when user opens my inbox. I've pieced together code from a few tutorials online and ended up with this:

```
 Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
     Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        if ((cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("read")) == 0)) {
                String SmsMessageId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put("read", true);
                getContentResolver().update(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), values, "read=0", null);
            }
```

I just want to mark all text messages as read in the onResume() function on this activity. My code may be a pile of crap, like i said it's mashed together from a few places. Corrections to, or alternatives to, my code would be very appreciated. Compiling the code with the sdk for 5.1, testing on 4.4, my app is the default SMS app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to mark all messages as read, you can do that in one go.

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(Telephony.Sms.READ, 1);
getContentResolver().update(Telephony.Sms.Inbox.CONTENT_URI, 
    values, Telephony.Sms.READ + "=0", null);
```

Comment: @DoğanKılıç What does being default app have to do with the query to update the message read status? That's a prerequisite for all database modifications from KK and onwards, not specific to this query.